# Powershell - script freezes after reading the first Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm having issues with my Powershell script - its meant to loop through a series of workbooks but it freezes after the first one. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
$(for ($i=3; $i -le $wb.sheets.count; $i++){

    $sh=$wb.Sheets.Item($i)
    $startCell = $sh.cells.item(1,2).EntireColumn.find("Application Name").Address()

    if($startCell -match '\$\w+\$(\d+)')
    {
        for($row=[int]$matches[1]+1; $sh.cells.item($row,2) -ne ""; $row++)
        {
            $apps = "" | Select appname,location,lob            
            $apps.appname = $sh.Cells($row, 2).Value2             
            $apps.location = $sh.Cells($row, 10).Value2            
            $apps.lob = $sh.Name            
            $apps        
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Which line does it freeze on (you have two loops here)?  If you don't know, load the script into PowerShell_ISE and single step through your script until you can find where it freezes.